# Remove and Update existing Calendar Event

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am following [this](https://gist.github.com/makadiyaharesh/b89f032977d5ffb39c86) gist, to `insert` event into `Calendar`

How do I `update` existing Calendar Event, which i have inserted earlier using below code:

```
public void addToCalender() throws ParseException {

        ......

        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendarId[0]);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Event Title");
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Event Description");
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Eevnt Location");
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startCalTime);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endCalTime);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
        event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

        Uri insertEventUri = AddEventActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(
                eventsUri, event);

        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
        reminders.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID,
                Long.parseLong(insertEventUri.getLastPathSegment()));
        reminders.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        reminders.put(Reminders.MINUTES, 10);

        AddEventActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(remainderUri, reminders);
    }
```

I would like to know, How do I :

```
1. Remove existing event

2. Update existing event
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can modify an event. Let's say its ID is eventID:

```
public void updateEvent(int eventID)
{
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "new title");
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "My cool event!");
    cr.update(eventUri, event, null, null);
}
```

To remove an event, you have two possibilities:

If you are a standard application:
Use the previous code and replace all the event.put by this one:

`event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DELETED, 1);`

If you are the SyncAdapter of the calendar and want a real deletion (The previous method just says that the event should be deleted and the one that follows must be used once the calendar is being synced :

```
public deleteEvent(Uri eventUri)
{
    cr.delete(event, null, null);
}
```

Where eventUri is the Uri of the event obtained as shown previously from the event ID.

For all of the previous methods, if you get an exception about not being in a sync adapter, you can use this:

```
public static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType)
{
    return uri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .build();
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Source: personnal code +  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Answer (score 1):

> ...
> Outlook in fact seems to respond to the rules defined in [RFC 2446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#page-19)

In summary you have to specify

> 

`METHOD:REQUEST` and `ORGANIZER:xxxxxxxx`

> ...
> [Please read the original answer by Tom Carter.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45969/revisions)